# Ubuntu Opens in Black Screen Using Lightdm But Working When Using GDM

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lightdm, gdm

Last time I installed lm-sensor (a package to know CPU Temperature) and restarted my system.

```
    $ sudo apt-get install lm-sensors 

    $ sudo sensors-detect

    $ sudo service module-init-tools start

    $ sensors
```

Since it did not work for me so I thought to restart my system. Then OMG! It started opening in a black screen after 'Ubuntu Splash Screen' on every restart. Sometime I got the message on top of the screen:

```
    Could not write bytes: Broken pipe
```

Non of keys were working except <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> which restarts the system. Neither <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> keys were working so that I could go to command line interface.

Only option remaing was to restart my system in Safe Mode. I restarted my system in safe mode and installed GDM (a display manager like lightdm) and configured it:

```
    First change the read only mode to read/write mode by simple using Fix Broken Packages 
    options listed there and then loged in as Root, then:
    # apt-get install gdm
    # dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

    then selected gdm from the list, and restarted my system.
    # reboot
```

This time a login screen appeared successfully and I was able to login to my system.
GDM display manager is good but I want to use lightdm since gdm doesn't allow me to log in automatically although I tried to change automatically login option from 'All Settings -> User Accounts'.

Please suggest me how can I fix this problem so that I can use lightdm. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/162078/147044?

Comment: No, not yet. Thanks for this link.. I searched a lot for my solution, did not get such a link that time. :) I will check it out and report soon..