# How to Remove Guest Session and Remote Login from Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, guest-session, remote-login

In the login screen, I see `Guest Session` and `Remote Login`.

I don't want these option, How can i remove them from my system and login screen both.

Comment: See this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/62566/71679 whats missing from that answer would be changing 'greeter-show-remote-login=false'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For Guest Session:

- [How do I disable the guest session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62564/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-session?rq=1)

#### For Remote Login:

1. Open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal).
2. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo -i                           # to have root privileges
   gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf   # to edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file
   ```
3. Add this line to the end of the file:

   ```
   greeter-show-remote-login=false
   ```
4. Save the file and close it.
5. Restart lightdm service (from tty1 with `sudo service lightdm restart`) or restart computer.

Comment: What if he would not be using `lightdm` or using some other display manager? like `gdm` or `xdm`?

Comment: @SauravKumar Then you could use [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button and specify your problems. For example: *How to remove Guest Session and Remote Login when I use gdm or xdm?* The OP said that he uses Ubuntu 13.04 and the default X display manager for Ubuntu 13.04 is [lightdm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. :) If you don't mind will give a minute and visit this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337116/ubuntu-opens-in-black-screen-using-lightdm-but-working-when-using-gdm Actually I have posted question, but it didn't catch any visit. I think you would know..

Comment: does `greeter-show-remote-login=fasle` disables remote login or just does not display remote login. My purpose is to disable remote login completly.

Comment: @HrithikRoshan It does both of them.

Comment: Thanks, I marked this as answer :) Keep Rocking bro. I have another problem, can you help me in this. http://askubuntu.com/questions/339651/after-installing-nvidia-301-again-and-lm-sensor-hddtemp-and-pfsensor-unity-is-lo

Comment: ***I'm facing this error...flow is sas shown below..***

gravity@gravityeducation:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for gravity: 

root@gravityeducation:~# gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

** (gedit:7524): WARNING **: Could not load Gedit repository: Typelib file for namespace 'GtkSource', version '3.0' not found

(gedit:7524): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

root@gravityeducation:~#

Comment: @silenTK That's a problem with your gedit editor. Try anotherone like nano for example.

Comment: when I open /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf in gedit, I can see only a blank file, am using(14.04).. Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

For remote login, uninstall:

remote-login-service
lightdm-remote-session-freerdp
lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure

This will prevent to be prompted to keep/replace your tweaked /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf when an update to the remote-login-service will be plublished.... because this way, you won't [need to] edit it to make the option disappear from the greeter.