# After Installing Nvidia 301 again and lm-sensor hddtemp and pfsensor Unity is lost

Tags: unity, 13.04, nvidia, indicator, temperature

First i would like to tell you, this is my 8th System error, I have reinstalled my Complete OS 7 times earlier than this, and Yet again new issue.

I have lost my Unity Dashboard, and Indicator panel.  I cannot drag and Drop and do nothing apart from running application via Terminal.

I can call them via terminal, but cannot use GUI options.[image]

Attached is Screenshot, you can see, it has no Indicator panel and no Unity menu.

**Summary :** of what i did when everything was working fine.

1. Removed Guest Login and Remote Login option via lightdm.
2. Installed System-indicator which show CPU Usage, Ram Usage and Network Transfer rate.
3. Installed Nvidia 301 via additional drive i.e,

`root@linux# jockey-kde &`

and installed Nvidia 301.
4. Installed lm-sensor hddtemp , and pfsensor.

**Summary :** of what i did after current situation.

1. De-activated Nvidia 301
2. Uninstalled lm-sensor, hddtemp and pfsensor.

But my Unity dashboard and indicator panel has not yet come :(

How can i get back, without re-installing my OS 8th Time now :(

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: no its not duplicate... i will update my ccsm screenshots

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me, however I think this is caused by graphics problems, not a missing Unity plugin. Please include some hardware information, especially `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: You might read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/125608/unity-3d-no-longer-works-after-installing-12-04

Comment: i have fixed this from here http://askubuntu.com/a/339684/188781

Answer (score 1):

Well, if someone has same problem, than here is possibel Fix :-

Method 1 :- [Try this, if this works]
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)
To, me this link didnot worked completly.

Method 2 :-

Step 1: Make your CD/USB Bootable and boot your system with it, Select Install Ubuntu Option which shows in boot time.

Step 2: And than Select option Re-install Ubuntu by keeping your all files intact.

Step 3: And Now let it re-install, once re-install is compelete, go to software center and install `Compiz Settings`.

Step 4: Your Screens and Dashboard are yet not there, so Just Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` for terminal and type `gksudo apt-get update`

Step 5: And than now follow -> [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

You can see something popping in your window, and rest thing will be happy time for you. :)

Good Luck.